# Generate rule that replaces if string matches pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, string-manipulation, rule

I have let's say a function `f[x]`, but for `x` I pass a string. And I want to replace that string with a number, if that string matches a pattern. Something like (using wildcard as an example):

```
f["model2cfs"]/.{"model2*"->9.9}
```

For the moment I am generating a big list of rules, but this is totally inpractical:

```
rulist={"model2cfs"->9.9, "model2xy"->9.9, "model2abc"->9.9}
```

And then I would do:

```
f[x]/.rulist
```

I have tried to find answers here on SE, and from this solution: [Replace elements that match pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76716/replace-elements-that-match-pattern), I have adapted it to:

```
lst={"model2cfs", "model2xy", "model2abc"}
altrule= Alternatives@@lst :> 9.9
f[x]/.altrule
```

This is more or less fine, but I would have to know in advance the list of possible "models2" , and what I want is to have it very general, so that for each "model2xxx" given, I get the correct replacement.

Comment: Use `StringMatchQ[]` in your replacement rule patterns: `f["model2cfs"] /. {str_String /; StringMatchQ[str, "model2*"] -> 9.9}`

Comment: I would nest @J.M. 's suggestion in a definition: `f[s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "model2*"]] := f[9.9]`